# Connect MS Access to MySQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

how can I connect MS Access to my databases? I have installed ODBC connector but I get errors when testing the connection.

**I have put in the following:**

**TCP/IP Server:** localhost + **Port:** 3306

**User:** My database username

**Password:** My database password

If I test these 100% correct information, I still get an error that connection is denied.

I think that there is a problem with the server name as I am just using a shared hosting where I use the database there. Any help??

Comment: "I am just using a shared hosting where I use the database there" - Check with the tech support department of your shared hosting provider. They will be able to tell you **(1)** whether or not it is possible to connect directly to your MySQL database over the Internet, and **(2)** if so, what server/port settings to use.

Comment: Aside - MySQL by default does not allow remote access. It must be enabled and even whitelisted for your user/IP.

Answer (score 0):

Hostname in "TCP/IP Server" must be the FQDN or IP address of the machine where MySQL is running.  We cannot tell you what that FQDN or IP address might be.  It is certainly not your Windows machine where MS Access is running (i.e., it is not `localhost`).